# How to add abstract<T> objects

Tags: c#, list, selenium

Please see this structure (from [here](https://automatetheplanet.com/advanced-page-object-pattern/)):

```
public abstract class AbstractPage<T> where T : AbstractPageEmenetsMap, new()
{
    protected readonly string url;
    protected VendorInfo vendorInfo;

    public AbstractPage(VendorInfo vendorInfo)
    {
        this.vendorInfo = vendorInfo;
        this.url = this.vendorInfo.Url;
    }

    public void Navigate()
    {
        WebDriver.Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(this.url);
    }

    protected T Map
    {
        get { return new T(); }
    }        
}

public abstract class AbstractPage<M, V> : AbstractPage<M>, ITest

    where M : AbstractPageEmenetsMap, new()
    where V : AbstractPageValidator<M>, new()
{
    public AbstractPage(VendorInfo vendorInfo)
        : base(vendorInfo) { }

    public V Validate()
    {
        return new V();
    }

    public void Login();
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Logout();
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Elements map:

```
public class AbstractPageEmenetsMap
{
    protected IWebDriver driver;
    public AbstractPageEmenetsMap()
    {
        driver = WebDriver.Driver;
    }
}
```

Validator:

```
public abstract class AbstractPageValidator<T> where T : AbstractPageEmenetsMap, new()
{
    protected T Map
    {
        get { return new T(); }
    }
}
```

Now this is Son class:

```
public class GmailPage : AbstractPage<GmailPageElementsMap, GmailPageValidator>
{
    public GmailPage() : base("http:...") { }
}
```

`Class` that holds all the `elements`:

```
public IWebElement EmailAddressTextBox
{
    get
    {
        return WebDriver.WebDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("identifierId")));
    }
}
```

And validator:

```
public class GmailPageValidator : AbstractPageValidator<GmailPageElementsMap>
{

}
```

So currently i have only 1 son but i about to add few more and i want to put them all in one `list` of type `AbstractPage`:

So if i want to create instance of my `Gmail` model:

```
AbstractPage<GmailPageElementsMap, GmailPageValidator> gmail = new GmailPage();
```

And as i mention i want to create one list that hold all this objects so this is what i have try:

```
static List<AbstractPage<AbstractPageEmenetsMap, AbstractPageValidator<AbstractPageEmenetsMap>>> list = null;
```

But i got this error:

> Error 1   'AnstractPage.AbstractPageValidator'
>   must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in
>   order to use it as parameter 'V' in the generic type or method
>   'AnstractPage.AbstractPage'

Any suggestions how to create this ind of `list` ?

Comment: Well, you did declare `V` with the type constraint `new()`... That would preclude uninstantiable classes. What would happen in `Validate` with an abstract class?

Comment: i forgot to add it, please see my update please

Comment: You've declared `V` as `new()` and in `Validate()` you say `new V()`. Now you have to choose... either `V` is `new()` ***or*** `V` can be `abstract`. You can't have both.

Comment: oh, can i have please simple code example ? (i am new developer)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to send an **abstract** validator here `...AbstractPageValidator<AbstracePageEmenetsMap>>> list = null;` when it's expecting something that's not **abstract**, like maybe your `GmailPageValidator`? If you want that to be able to store **abstract** stuff you have to remove the `new()` keyword, but that would in turn screw up your `Validate()` function... You've got some design decisions to make.